# After reaching daily or monthly limit on questions, can I find out what is the earliest time when I can post a new question?

Tags: support, rate-limiting

After reaching daily or monthly limit on questions, can I find out what is the earliest time when I can post a new question?

Comment: Doesnt it tell you"wait X days" when you ask another question if you've hit a limit?

Comment: Which rate-limit are you hitting: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide?

Comment: no it doesn't @Patrice

Comment: Hmmmm then it probably should :p

Comment: Looks like you've hit the "6 in a day" limit... So either UTC midnight or 24 hours after the earliest of the most recent 6 (can't remember which one it is)

Comment: i hit monthly limit, which makes it more difficult to find out when i can post again. @JonClements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to work it out.

Do a search for your questions that were created in the last 29 days.

```
user:me is:q created:29d.. deleted:all
```

<sub>(Note that `deleted:all` is only available if you're a 10k+ user)</sub>

This at the current time gives you a result of 48 questions. Since the rate limiting is 50 questions over a *rolling* 30 day period (and at most 6 per day), that means 2 questions (the 50 limit minus the 48 that'll still count for the last 30 days) will become available tomorrow (eg: the 2 questions created exactly 30 days ago are no longer considered).

You can then tweak that search to `28d` for instance and you can work out that if you ask both questions tomorrow, you'll only be able to ask 1 the following day etc...

Comment: Thanks. Are there references which list all the available fields including "user", "is", "created", and "deleted" and their meanings? Do the fields only apply to the search box of stackoverflow and stackexchange sites, or also to other scenarios outside stackexchange and stackoverflow?

Comment: When you mention 2 questions will become available tomorrow, is "tomorrow" a calendar day relative to some time zone, or is "tomorrow" defined as 24 hours starting from some time?

Comment: @Tim next day/tomorrow is UTC midnight... the search stuff is available on any SE site in its search bar - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching for what's available.

Comment: Thanks. Can your method work for daily limit?

Comment: @Tim just go to your profile and look at the date of the last 6 questions? :)

Comment: Is it correct your method only works on calendar day basis, but not hour/minute basis?

Comment: @Tim search is only so granular as to day level

Comment: Is daily limit defined on calendar day basis, or 24 hours starting from the 6th last question?

Comment: Calendar day @Tim... As explained in the meta post you were linked to in the comments on your question. Starting to see why you're hitting the question limit :-P

Comment: Thanks. Jon. I just reached the 50 questions per month limit, and found that `user:me is:q created:29d.. deleted:all` says 48 posts. I wonder why not 50 posts? Does the query miss some posts?