# Where I can check the number of questions asked and remaining in a month?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban, rate-limiting

I have been asking questions and giving answers on the Stack Overflow since a long time. One day suddenly, I have got a notification while I was trying to post the question. The notification says *"You can only post 50 questions in 30 days"*. Then I came to know about the limit on Stack Overflow regarding the question posting.

But this was not a notification to me before. I wanted to know where I can check whether how many questions I have asked in a month. I even didn't got from where the month start and 30 days are counted for my account on Stack Overflow.

Is there a way to know about it?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351790/after-reaching-daily-or-monthly-limit-on-questions-can-i-find-out-what-is-the-e

Comment: Is there nothing available with Stackoverflow to give a direct stats instead of me checking it with command? Why I can't get it on my profile page? or with some notification?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: You can see it in your profile, click the Activity > Questions > Newest tabs Unfortunately the sorting has been broken lately so you'll have to interpolate a bit.  You are not close to 50 questions this month so you are probably sharing your IP address with other SO askers.

Comment: Is that the issue of IP? I use my work place computer sometimes.

Comment: Your IP doesn't show as hobbled so it's not that - you did reach a point where you did hit 50 within 30 days though. Note that deleted questions still count as having been asked - so all those allauth questions you asked recently then deleted still count for the 30 day rolling period..

Comment: ok I gt it.. I was experimenting with allauth and was troublesome. So is that the reason behind me getting such a message. Ok I got it now.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no direct way of searching for this, neither in a notification nor in your profile.

As Jon Clements points out in his comment, you can search for all questions asked by you in the past 30 days with custom search syntax, but that's about it.

Most people never hit or even get close to the 50 questions a month limit so it's understandable that dev time wasn't used to make an easier-access version of this indicator.

Comment: Since the number also varies - it's up to 6 questions a day for up to 50 in a rolling 30 day period, plus lots of poorly received questions might lead to temporary (one or two days to try to help the user stop digging themselves deeper) question blocks or full blocks or the user might be on a temporarily rate restricted network etc... it'd be a rather unnecessary and expensive calculation that's only currently run when trying to submit a question to put it somewhere on the profile page or similar.

Comment: @JonClements It's also not relevant enough. Very few users hit that rate limit and users who hit the block are warned multiple times beforehand

Comment: Indeed. Just pointing out there's a lot of factors of whether you can post or not in itself - trying to display an accurate number of "how many are left" - isn't simple, is liable to change at any time on other factors, and is expensive to attempt to calculate outside of checking on question submission.